# ls and date showing different file dates

Tags: linux

touching a file and showing 'date' show different hours and minutes, off by 7 hours and 7 minutes or something like that.  What clock do I need to update?

```
[root@dev3-mirth02 mirth]# date
Thu Apr 30 10:13:26 EDT 2015

[root@dev3-mirth02 mirth]# touch foo
[root@dev3-mirth02 mirth]# ls -lart foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Apr 30 04:22 foo
```

Comment: What is the value of the $TZ variable? What do `date +%s` and `stat foo` output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you don't say it, I strongly suspect that the file is NFS mounted or in some other way, retrieved over the network. If the file is NFS mounted, the file will take its time from the system where the file is located. I think if you log onto that system, you will find that the time of the file and the time of the system agree.

Comment: I think this is the root cause, the file is NFS mounted, I'll need to figure out why the other system is so off.  Thanks!